# Function not defined - Python

Tags: python, function, class

I'm trying to create a class in Python and the pLink function is giving a "not defined" error message when being called.

```
class Book:
    def __init__(bk, name, ISBN, genre, form, rating, author, language, publisher, link):
        bk.name = name
        bk.ISBN = ISBN
        bk.genre = genre
        bk.form = form
        bk.rating = rating
        bk.author = author
        bk.language = language
        bk.publisher = publisher
        bk.link = link
        
    def __repr__(bk):
        rep = 'Book:      ' + bk.name + "\n" + "ISBN:      " + str(bk.ISBN) + "\n" + "Genre:     " + bk.genre + "\n" + "Format:    " + bk.form + "\n" + "Rating:    " + str(bk.rating) + "\n" + "Author:    " + bk.author + "\n" + "Language:  " + bk.language + "\n" + "Publisher: " + bk.publisher + "\n" ''
        return rep
    
    def pLink(bk):
        pl = "Here's the link to purchase the book: " + bk.link + ""
        return pl
    
b1 = Book("Where the Red Fern Grows", 9780399551239, "Children's Literature", "Hardcover", 4.1, a1.name, "English", "Doubleday", "https://www.amazon.com/Where-Fern-Grows-Wilson-Rawls/dp/0399551239/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2UQWGKLQ7KB7F&keywords=where+the+red+fern+grows+hardcover&qid=1663797713&sprefix=where+the+red+fern+grows+hardcove%2Caps%2C107&sr=8-1")
```

[image]

Any ideas on what I'm missing here? It works if I don't indent the function.

Comment: You need to say `print(b1.pLink())`.  Note that, by convention, you should replace all instances of `bk` with `self`.  The first parameter in a class method is ALWAYS called `self`.  The language doesn't enforce that, but your code will be laughed at unless you follow the convention.

Comment: The proper call is `b1.pLink()`, not `pLink(b1)`.

Comment: Concerning the name of the first parameter in your methods you should read the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments): "Always use `self` for the first argument to instance methods."

Answer (score 0):

You need to call that function from the class.

You can not use any function inside a class from outside you need to go in the class and call it

And in this case you need to create an object and call your function through it

```py
Obj = Book()
Obj.pLink()
```

Comment: No, in this case the method should be called from an instance of the class with `b1.pLink()`.

Comment: Oh yes you are right.  I did not notice that variable who will take the object as parameter because its name is not self that was confusing hhh. Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

The closest way you have done that I can think of is this:

```
class Book:
    def __init__(bk, name, ISBN, genre, form, rating, author, language, publisher, link):
        bk.name = name
        bk.ISBN = ISBN
        bk.genre = genre
        bk.form = form
        bk.rating = rating
        bk.author = author
        bk.language = language
        bk.publisher = publisher
        bk.link = link
        
    def __repr__(bk):
        rep = 'Book:      ' + bk.name + "\n" + "ISBN:      " + str(bk.ISBN) + "\n" + "Genre:     " + bk.genre + "\n" + "Format:    " + bk.form + "\n" + "Rating:    " + str(bk.rating) + "\n" + "Author:    " + bk.author + "\n" + "Language:  " + bk.language + "\n" + "Publisher: " + bk.publisher + "\n" ''
        return rep
    
    @staticmethod
    def pLink(bk):
        pl = "Here's the link to purchase the book: " + bk.link + ""
        return pl
    
b1 = Book("Where the Red Fern Grows", 9780399551239, "Children's Literature", "Hardcover", 4.1, a1.name, "English", "Doubleday", "https://www.amazon.com/Where-Fern-Grows-Wilson-Rawls/dp/0399551239/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2UQWGKLQ7KB7F&keywords=where+the+red+fern+grows+hardcover&qid=1663797713&sprefix=where+the+red+fern+grows+hardcove%2Caps%2C107&sr=8-1")
```

Now you can use:

```
print(Book.pLink(b1))
```